# Does VPN encrpyt Restful connection?

Tags: rest, vpn, openvpn

I have a college project that I need to encrypt a connection between a remote server (aws, etc) and a local client. I've setup an openvpn server and have no trouble connecting the clients and I can see the encrypted connection with Wireshark searching for openvpn packets.

But my teacher keeps asking if the data comes encrypted when someone uses a service like aws and I don't know how to answer or how to test it.

Comment: How about using HTTPS?

Comment: @tkausl so I would set my own SSL server?